# Как проверить значение какого-то символа в String? C#

Tags: c#, строки

Предположим есть переменная типа String "12 строка 234 что-то еще". Как можно проверить есть ли в этой переменной символ "ч"?

Comment: попробуйте `ValStr.Contain("ч");`

Comment: @Monomax ValStr.Contains('ч');

Comment: Спасибо, помогло.

Comment: @tym32167 согласен, опечатка вышла, не допечатал "s".

Comment: @Monomax ну и я перегрузку для символа вызвал, а не для строки

Answer (score 0):

Решено. Спасибо за ответ.
Чтобы проверить наличие символа или символов в перeменой типа String: [`имя переменной`.`Contains("то что надо найти");`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.string.contains?view=netframework-4.7.2) Чтобы проверить добавляете это все в `if`

Пример:

```
str.Contains("hello");
```

Comment: В языках программирование "реализованные константы" принято называть "литералы". Ознакомьтесь с разделом "строковые литералы" в с#.

Comment: Ну, и на заметку: метод Contains реализован просто как return ( IndexOf(value, StringComparison.Ordinal) >=0 ) - см. referencesource. Т.е. со всякими умлаутами и диакритическими знаками может быть нюанс.